# Hash function- Right shifitng

Tags: c++, shift, hash-function

i have to implement this hash function

> "h(k)=((A*k)*mod(2^32))rsh(32-r)".

Where rsh(32-r) is right shifting a number. How can i do this right shifting. I am confused as i don't know how many times it will right shift the number ? Also it is not mentioned in my PDF. And also table size=m=2^r. Therefore r=logm. 
**It is mandatory to use this hash function.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: it will shift by 32 - r places

Comment: is there any code in c++ that will help me out @MarcoA. ?

Comment: @user3738548 Plenty at the link in the first comment.

Comment: Yes i go through it but still i am not getting it properly.

Comment: Result of (32-r) will be a constant if this constant will be pass to a right shift function then how will this function shift a constant ! My confusion is simply this @WhozCraig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the equivalent function:

```
uint32_t rsh(uint32_t num, uint8_t pad) {
     return num >> pad;
}

h = rsh((A*k)*mod(2^32), 32 - r);
```